# How to show record name instead of record count for one2many field in tree view /kanban view odoo

Tags: javascript, treeview, odoo-8, odoo-9, openerp-8

[image]I have two one2many field one inside the other,the o2m field records are shown in the numeric counts like (3record) in the outer o2m field.
How to show record name instead of record count for one2many field in tree view

Answer (score 0):

```
 <tree string="Customer Segment(Industry)" >
      <field name="name" string="Customer Segment"/>
      <field name="industry_image" widget="image" />
      <field name="schedule_list_ids"/>
 </tree>
```

this will display like this

[image: Showing record name instead of count- tree view]

In the form view I have like the following

```
           <form string="Industries List">
                <sheet>
                   <group>
                         <field name="name" style="width:30%%" string="Customer Segment"/>
                         <field name="industry_image" widget="image" width="100px" height="100px" />
                         <field name="schedule_list_ids"/>
                   </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
```

[image: Showing record name instead of count- formview]

Comment: Thanks sfx,but mine actual problem is not this...I have kanban view and inside that kanban view i have a o2m field ,but the records of o2m field shown on kanban view are in numeric form like..(1 record) ,(3 record).but in actual i want values to be displayed and not numeric records.